# How to pass variable from one javascript file to other javascript file of different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass this usr_id from current javascript file to second javascript in which i have to use this id in the form to update.

```js
delUser.addEventListener("click", function() {
  $("input:checkbox[name=u_id]:checked").each(function(){
  array_Online3.push($(this).val());});
  
 console.log(array_Online3[0]);
  //console.log();

  usr_id=array_Online3[0];
```

I have used multiple solution like  global vairable by accessing it with window.usr_id but its giving output as undefined.

```js
document.getElementById("user_id").value=window.usr_id;
   var id=document.getElementById("user_id").value;
```

other solution is also not working

```js
var globalVariable={
       usr_id: usr_id
   
    };
```

```js
document.getElementById("user_id").value=globalVariable.usr_id1;
```

Comment: why don't you store it in localStorage ?

Comment: If you are trying to access the data on actual _"different pages"_ you can't store it in some variable, as that memory will be lost upon navigating to a different page. You would need to use other api like cookies, localStorage like George mentions, or passing as a url parameter

Answer (score 1):

Save it in localStorage like George Bailey suggested in the comment section.

```
// Store
localStorage.usrId = "Smith101";

// Retrieve
localStorage.usrId; //will return "Smith101"

//Remove
localStorage.removeItem("usrId");
```

Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for more info on how localStorage works